# What is the time complexity of this function? And how to improve it

Tags: python, performance

I can't figure out what's the time complexity of the function below.
Is it O(n^3) since the for loops have a linear runtime and the if-statement probably has one aswell. Or is it something else?

```py
def maxProfit(self, prices: List[int]) -> int:
    profit=0
    for i in range(len(prices)):
        for j in range(i+1,len(prices)):
            if prices[j]-prices[i]>profit:
                profit=prices[j]-prices[i]
    return profit
```

Comment: the 'if' is not O(n) / linear, it's constant.
But, yes, the two nested loops are basically O(n^2) (even though the inner loop has reduced iterations compared to the outer)

Comment: Part of building a good question is trying to make its answers as useful to other people as possible. "What is the time complexity of this function?" isn't something _even people with other questions about time complexity_ will be likely to be helped on clicking through on, because "this function" will be different for each person asking the question. (Back in the site's earlier days, we had a "too localized" close reason that was directly on-point).

Comment: That said, note that Stack Overflow is focused on questions about practice, not theory; there's a separate Stack Exchange site for the latter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can improve the complexity to O(n) by retaining the minimum-to-date on a single pass through the list:

```
def maxProfit(self, prices: List[int]) -> int:
    profit = 0
    min_so_far = prices[0]
    for p in prices:
        if p < min_so_far:
            min_so_far = p
        elif p - min_so_far > profit:
            profit = p - min_so_far
    return profit
```